# Need to sort array in ASC or DESC order by their title value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Below is my array,

```
     Array
   (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [topic_title] => gff
        [title] => gff
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [topic_title] => new toipic
        [title] => new toipic
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [topic_title] => Welcome!
        [title] =>Welcome!
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [entry_title] => sdasdad
        [title] => sdasdad
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [event_title] => red
        [title] => red
    )
[5] => Array
    (
        [event_title] => sa
        [title] => sa          
    )
[6] => Array
    (
        [event_title] => sadasd
        [title] => sadasd
    )
[7] => Array
    (
        [event_title] => Test Event
        [title] => Test Event
    )
)
```

I want the output like below

```
   Array(
[0] => Array
        (
            [event_title] => Test Event
            [title] => Test Event
        )
 [1] => Array
        (
            [event_title] => Welcome!
            [title] => Welcome!
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [event_title] => sa
            [title] => sa
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [entry_title] => sdasdad
            [title] => sdasdad
        )    
    [4] => Array
        (
            [event_title] => sadasd
            [title] => sadasd
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [event_title] => red
            [title] => red
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [topic_title] => new toipic
            [title] => new toipic
        )     
    [7] => Array
        (
            [topic_title] => gff
            [title] => gff
        )
)
```

This is the print code from PHP 5.6.

I uses usort() function but didn't get required one. I am not able to sort array in assenting or descending order by their title key.

This array  I am getting  from different queries an d after that I merge it in one array but not able to sort it by title value

Comment: `I am getting from different queries` ... if the source of this array/data is a SQL database, then I think we should be doing the sorting in the database, not in your PHP code.  Please include the relevant queries.

Comment: How can `'Welcome!'` come after `'Test Event'` but `'red'` come after `'sa'`?

Comment: @Nick  actually he merger two arrays coming from two queries and put them sorted manner in his desired output. That's why it's confusing

Comment: @AlivetoDie especially since there's no way to see where one query ends and the next begins...

Comment: Add your code with usort() first and edit your question to tell where it fails

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$array = Array ( Array("topic_title" => "aatoipic","title" => "new toipic"),Array("event_title" => "Test Event","title" => "Test Event"),Array("topic_title" => "Welcome!", "title" => "Welcome!"),Array("entry_title" => "sdasdad","title" => "p",),Array("event_title" => "red","title" => "k",),Array("event_title" => "sa","title" => "sa"),Array("event_title" => "sadasd","title" => "d"),Array("topic_title" => "gff", "title" => "gff"),Array( "topic_title" => "new toipic","title" => "h"));

    $arr  = $array;
    $sort = array();
    foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
        $sort['title'][$k] = $v['title'];
    }

    array_multisort($sort['title'], SORT_ASC, $arr);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr);
```

Output will come :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [event_title] => Test Event [title] => Test Event ) [1] => Array ( [topic_title] => Welcome! [title] => Welcome! ) [2] => Array ( [event_title] => sadasd [title] => d ) [3] => Array ( [topic_title] => gff [title] => gff ) [4] => Array ( [topic_title] => new toipic [title] => h ) [5] => Array ( [event_title] => red [title] => k ) [6] => Array ( [topic_title] => aatoipic [title] => new toipic ) [7] => Array ( [entry_title] => sdasdad [title] => p ) [8] => Array ( [event_title] => sa [title] => sa ) )
```

Comment: let me check first

Comment: @Harsh  untill and unless you show query code and how your created your array, nothing will going to work

Comment: I use above one but not sorted array, my array as below
` $arr =  Array (
Array("topic_title" => "aatoipic","title" => "new toipic"),Array("event_title" => "Test Event","title" => "Test Event"),Array("topic_title" => "Welcome!", "title" => "Welcome!"),Array("entry_title" => "sdasdad","title" => "p",),Array("event_title" => "red","title" => "k",),Array("event_title" => "sa","title" => "sa"),Array("event_title" => "sadasd","title" => "d"),Array("topic_title" => "gff", "title" => "gff"),Array( "topic_title" => "new toipic","title" => "h"));`

Comment: but your output is not in alphabetical sort, I want title in alphabetical order

Answer (score 0):

[usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) will do the trick:

```
usort($array, function($x, $y) {
    return strcasecmp($x['title'], $y['title']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_multisort() to achieve the desired result.

E.g

```
$title = array();
foreach ($post as $key => $row)
{
    $title[$key] = $row['title'];
}
array_multisort($title, SORT_DESC, $post);
```

Comment: I use this code, but still I am not getting proper output Array
`(
    [0] => sdasdad
    [1] => sadasd
    [2] => sa
    [3] => red
    [4] => new toipic
    [5] => new toipic
    [6] => new toipic
    [7] => gff
    [8] => aaanew toipic
    [9] => Welcome!
    [10] => Test Event
)` this is not in order

Comment: @Harsh  show your queries code and the code where you assign queries result to your array.

Comment: I use `foreach ($post as $key => $row)
{
    $title[$key] = $row['title'];
}
array_multisort($title, SORT_DESC, $post);

echo "<pre>"; print_r($title);`

Comment: @Harsh Why are you printing `$title` ? once you use `array_multisort` your main array `$post` will have all the titles arranged in descending order

Comment: I try to print $post, but still not able to sort by title (alphabetic) my array is `$post = Array ( Array("topic_title" => "aatoipic","title" => "new toipic"),Array("event_title" => "Test Event","title" => "Test Event"),Array("topic_title" => "Welcome!", "title" => "Welcome!"),Array("entry_title" => "sdasdad","title" => "p",),Array("event_title" => "red","title" => "k",),Array("event_title" => "sa","title" => "sa"),Array("event_title" => "sadasd","title" => "d"),Array("topic_title" => "gff", "title" => "gff"),Array( "topic_title" => "new toipic","title" => "h")); `

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `usort` with a [strcasecmp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php):

```
function querySort ($x, $y) {
     return strcasecmp($x['title'], $y['title']);
}

usort($myArray, 'querySort');
```